# copy folder contents using maven's unpack-dependency

Tags: maven, maven-plugin

I have a zip which i have defined in my dependencies as shown below

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.project.mine</groupId>
    <artifactId>${projectname}</artifactId>
    <version>${projectversion}</version>
    <classifier>bin</classifier>
    <type>zip</type>
</dependency>
```

This zip contains two folders namely

1. Folder 1
2. Folder 2

I am trying to copy the content of this zip as shown below

```
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>unpack-one</id>
            <phase>generate-resources</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>unpack-dependencies</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <includeGroupIds>com.project.mine</includeGroupIds>
                <includeArtifactIds>projectone</includeArtifactIds>
                <type>zip</type>
                <outputDirectory>${target.assets}/www</outputDirectory>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
        <execution>
            <id>unpack-two</id>
            <phase>generate-resources</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>unpack-dependencies</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <includeGroupIds>com.project.mine</includeGroupIds>
                <includeArtifactIds>${projectname}</includeArtifactIds>
                <type>zip</type>
                <outputDirectory>${target.assets}/www/ProjectOneContent</outputDirectory>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

The problem that i face is that it copies both the folders. 
I want  to just copy the contents of 'Folder2' (which can be subfolders, images, js, css etc) inside 'ProjectOneContent' folder.

Note: ProjectOneContent is created after first execution is completed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I achieved it using [maven-antrun plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-antrun-plugin/usage.html).
To achieve this first i unpack dependency at a temporary location and then once unpacked, i copied each resource one by one using antrun at desired location

Answer (score 0):

Well, from what I can see, you are not defining any `includes` patterns (as explained [here](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/unpack-mojo.html#includes)). Add the following to your `<configuration>`:

```
<includes>Folder2/**</includes>
```